# Android(Java): DRYer approach using interfaces and less duplication

Tags: java, android, interface

Is there a good way using interfaces lessen the duplication here. Currently there are 3 types(`kelvin`,`celcius`,`fahrenheit`) of conversion which results in 6 combinations.

Is there a more scale able way of handling this, lets say we want to add 2 more types (total of 5) its going to start to become a bit of a hassle to maintain all the combinations?

Here is the code:

```
public class ConvertTemperatureJava {
        private static final String TAG = "ConvertTemperatureJava";

    static String TEMPERATURE_KELVIN = "kelvin";
    static String TEMPERATURE_CELCIUS = "celsius";
    static String TEMPERATURE_FAHRENHEIT = "fahrenheit";

    private float inputValue = 0;
    private String inputUnit, outputUnit = null;

    public void setInputValue(String inputValueString) {
        // convert input to correct type
        try {
            this.inputValue = Float.parseFloat(inputValueString);
        } catch (NumberFormatException e) {
            Log.e(TAG, e.getMessage());
            this.inputValue = 0;
        }
    }

    public void setInputUnit(String inputUnit) {
        this.inputUnit = inputUnit;
    }

    public void setOutputUnit(String outputUnit) {
        this.outputUnit = outputUnit;
    }

    public float convert() {
        // same units, no conversion required
        if (inputUnit != null && outputUnit != null && inputValue != 0) {
            if (inputUnit.equalsIgnoreCase(outputUnit)) {
                return inputValue;
            }

            // kelvin and celsius
            if (inputUnit.equalsIgnoreCase(TEMPERATURE_KELVIN) && outputUnit.equalsIgnoreCase(TEMPERATURE_CELCIUS)) {
                return kelvinToCelsius(inputValue);
            }
            if (inputUnit.equalsIgnoreCase(TEMPERATURE_CELCIUS) && outputUnit.equalsIgnoreCase(TEMPERATURE_KELVIN)) {
                return celsiusToKelvin(inputValue);
            }

            // kelvin and fahrenheit
            if (inputUnit.equalsIgnoreCase(TEMPERATURE_KELVIN) && outputUnit.equalsIgnoreCase(TEMPERATURE_FAHRENHEIT)) {
                return kelvinToFahrenheit(inputValue);
            }
            if (inputUnit.equalsIgnoreCase(TEMPERATURE_FAHRENHEIT) && outputUnit.equalsIgnoreCase(TEMPERATURE_KELVIN)) {
                return fahrenheitToKelvin(inputValue);
            }

            // celsius and fahrenheit
            if (inputUnit.equalsIgnoreCase(TEMPERATURE_CELCIUS) && outputUnit.equalsIgnoreCase(TEMPERATURE_FAHRENHEIT)) {
                return celsiusToFahrenheit(inputValue);
            }
            if (inputUnit.equalsIgnoreCase(TEMPERATURE_FAHRENHEIT) && outputUnit.equalsIgnoreCase(TEMPERATURE_CELCIUS)) {
                return fahrenheitToCelsius(inputValue);
            }
        }

        // fallback
        return 0;
    }

    private float kelvinToCelsius(float input) {
        return input - 273.15f;
    }

    private float celsiusToKelvin(float input) {
        return input + 273.15f;
    }

    private float kelvinToFahrenheit(float input) {
        return (input * 1.8f) - 459.67f;
    }

    private float fahrenheitToKelvin(float input) {
        return (input + 459.67f) * (5f / 9f);
    }

    private float celsiusToFahrenheit(float input) {
        return (input * 1.8f) + 32f;
    }

    private float fahrenheitToCelsius(float input) {
        return (input - 32f) / 1.8f;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Do like what the United Nations does with languages. Pick one unit as the intermediary unit (like English is at the UN), and then define all of your other converters in terms of going to/from that standard unit.

For example, you could pick Kelvin as the standard unit, and then implement `celsiusToFahrenheit(input)` as `kelvinToFahrenheit(celsiusToKelvin(input))`.